# what's the best way to send a variable using method get with express, mysql and node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I'm building a web site using node.js express MySQL and boostrap, when I try to send a variable against method get for to do a query to the database, it's seem doesn't work, because there's no a good render. this is my code:

```
app.get('/reservaciones/leer/:id', function(req, res) {
            var idreservacion = req.params.idreservacion;
            crud.get_leer_reservacion(req,idreservacion,function(data_leer){

               res.render'../views/leer.html',data:data_leer});
            });
    });

exports.get_leer_reservacion = function(req,idreservacion,fn){
// here the query
connection.query('select * from reservacion where idreservacion = '"+idreservacion+"'', function(err,rows){
if(err){
throw err;
}
return fn(rows);
});
};
```

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxFTEy90zOKAfmJOXzR3NDFLa081NUtEUFU4LWhuN2ZUTDMtVktPeHlYbVUzWW02a2pGWEk&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
res.render'../views/leer.html',data:data_leer});
```

should be:

```
(outside of app.get:)
app.use('views', '../views');

(inside:)
res.render('leer',{data:data_leer});
```

If your problem is actually getting the templated data into the page I suggest the `ejs` npm package and templating system, you would use `<%= data =>` to template in the value

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
app.get('/reservaciones/leer/:id', function(req, res) {
        var idreservacion = req.params.idreservacion;
```

You define a parameter called `id`, but you retrieve a parameter called `idreservacion`. Try something like this:

```
app.get('/reservaciones/leer/:id', function(req, res) {
        var idreservacion = req.params.id;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but its doesn´t work, my problem is when i try to res.render('../views/leer.html',data:data_leer}); ....